# How can I send command line output through node.js server-sent-event and show it in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I am relatively new to JavaScript and  I'm setting up a server sent event (sse) with node.js using some examples I see in the internet. My question is how can I send the output of the **lsExample()** command line function throught the **res.write()** function to show it in the browser.

```
var SSE = require('sse')
  , http = require('http');

//var  exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write(here);
  res.end('okay');
});


const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);



async function lsExample() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
console.log('stdout:', stdout);
console.log('stderr:', stderr);
}

lsExample();


server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  var sse = new SSE(server);
  sse.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.send('hi there!');
  });
});
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var http = require('http');
var SSE = require('sse');

//var  exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  lsExample().then( (result)=>{
    res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
    res.end('');
  },(err)=> { 
    res.write("error");
    res.end('');
  });
 
});


const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);



 function lsExample() {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
        resolve({ "stdout" :  stdout, "stderr" : stderr});
        } catch (err){
           reject(err);
        }

      });
}


server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  var sse = new SSE(server);
  sse.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.send('hi there!');
  });
});
```

Comment: lsExample.then((result)=> {
     res.write(result);
     res.end('okay');
  });
It can be used inside "sse.on" block also, i.e. when client connects.

Comment: Not sure how to do it in see.on block and I got this error from the first option:

fil.js:18
  lsExample.then((result)=> {
            ^
TypeError: lsExample.then is not a function

Comment: Hi Tarun. Is there a way in which JSON.stringify(result) shows the result of the command in browser like it is shown in console but not in json format?

Comment: What kind of output you want to display, can you give me some sample output.

Comment: For example the output of df -m  displaying the free disk space in columns.


Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3996816        0   3996816   0% /dev
tmpfs             804624    10020    794604   2% /run
/dev/sda9       68117056 18036160  46597712  28% /
tmpfs            4023116    29848   3993268   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4023116        0   4023116   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         88832    88832         0 100% /snap/simplescreenrecorder/1

Comment: var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  lsExample().then( (result)=>{
    res.write(result.stdout);
    res.end('');
  },(err)=> { 
    res.write("error");
    res.end('');
  });
 
});

Comment: res.write(result.stdout);